# "Image not found" error while using MaterialComponents framework

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, material-components, material-components-ios

"I am using MaterialComponents framework. After installing using pod it hides some of my view controllers in storyboard, so that i cant edit it, but the program runs fine. Reinstalling it removes the error"

It also highlights an error like **"Failed to render and update auto layout status for UIViewController():dlopen..ionalization Referenced from: MaterialComponents.framework Reason: image not found"**

Could someone please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems not relate to that framework but the pod install was corrupted somewhere. You could try this:

1. Clean project: Product -> Clean Build Folder (or Command + Shift + K)
2. Delete derived data of your projects: rm -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YOUR_PROJECT-xxxxx
3. Restart Xcode
4. Do pod install again